# Update initial condition in ODE solver each time step

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, ode, numerical-integration

I am wanting to solve a system of ODEs where for the first 30,000 seconds, I want one of my state variables to start from the same initial value. After those 30,000 seconds, I want to change the initial value of that state variable to something different and simulate the system for the rest of time. Here is my code:

```
def ode_rhs(y, t):
    ydot[0] = -p[7]*y[0]*y[1] + p[8]*y[8] + p[9]*y[8]
    ydot[1] = -p[7]*y[0]*y[1] + p[8]*y[8]
    ydot[2] = -p[10]*y[2]*y[3] + p[11]*y[9] + p[12]*y[9]
    ydot[3] = -p[13]*y[3]*y[6] + p[14]*y[10] + p[15]*y[10] - p[10]*y[2]*y[3] + p[11]*y[9] + p[9]*y[8] - p[21]*y[3]
    ydot[4] = -p[19]*y[4]*y[5] - p[16]*y[4]*y[5] + p[17]*y[11] - p[23]*y[4] + y[7]*p[20]
    ydot[5] = -p[19]*y[4]*y[5] + p[15]*y[10] - p[16]*y[4]*y[5] + p[17]*y[11] + p[18]*y[11] + p[12]*y[9] - p[22]*y[5]
    ydot[6] = -p[13]*y[3]*y[6] + p[14]*y[10] - p[22]*y[6] - p[25]*y[6] - p[23]*y[6]
    ydot[7] = 0
    ydot[8] = p[7]*y[0]*y[1] - p[8]*y[8] - p[9]*y[8]
    ydot[9] = p[10]*y[2]*y[3] - p[11]*y[9] - p[12]*y[9] - p[21]*y[9]
    ydot[10] = p[13]*y[3]*y[6] - p[14]*y[10] - p[15]*y[10] - p[22]*y[10] - p[21]*y[10] - p[23]*y[10]
    ydot[11] = p[19]*y[4]*y[5] + p[16]*y[4]*y[5] - p[17]*y[11] - p[18]*y[11] - p[22]*y[11] - p[23]*y[11]
    ydot[12] = p[22]*y[10] + p[22]*y[11] + p[22]*y[5] + p[22]*y[6] + p[21]*y[10] + p[21]*y[3] + p[21]*y[9] + p[24]*y[13] + p[25]*y[6] + p[23]*y[10] + p[23]*y[11] + p[23]*y[4] + p[23]*y[6]
    ydot[13] = p[15]*y[10] + p[18]*y[11] - p[24]*y[13]
    return ydot

pysb.bng.generate_equations(model)
alias_model_components()
p = np.array([k.value for k in model.parameters])
ydot = np.zeros(len(model.odes))
y0 = np.zeros(len(model.odes))
y0[0:7] = p[0:7]
t = np.linspace(0.0,1000000.0,100000)
r = odeint(ode_rhs,y0,t)
```

So, in other words, I want to set y0[1] to the same value (100) each time `odeint` is called for the first 30,000 seconds. I'm effectively trying to let the system equilibrate for an amount of time before inputing a signal into the system. I thought about doing something like `if t < 30000: y0[1] = 100` as the first line of my `ode_rhs()` function, but I'm not quite sure that works.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow you, but initial conditions are initial, say at t=0. I doesn't make sense to change the initial conditions after the initial time. Besides, you're only calling `odeint` once. What does "each time odeint is called for the first 30,000 seconds" mean?

Comment: Why does this question have a `matlab` tag?  And why not `scipy`?

Comment: You're right - it should have been tagged as `scipy` and not `matlab`. Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds like you want y1(t) to remain constant (with the value 100) for the
equilibration phase.  You can do this by ensuring that dy1(t)/dt = 0 during this
phase.  There are (at least) two ways you can accomplish that.  The first is to
modify the calculation of `ydot[1]` in `ode_rhs` as follows:

```
if t < 30000:
    ydot[1] = 0.0
else:
    ydot[1] = -p[7]*y[0]*y[1] + p[8]*y[8]
```

and use the intitial condition 100 for `y[1]`.

Note that this introduces a discontinuity in the right-hand side of the system,
but the adaptive solver used by `odeint` (the Fortran code LSODA) is usually robust enough to handle it.

Here's a self-contained example.  I've made `p` and `t1` arguments to `ode_rhs`.
`t1` is the duration of the equilibration phase.

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.integrate import odeint
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


def ode_rhs(y, t, p, t1):
    ydot[0] = -p[0]*y[0]*y[1] + p[1]*y[2] + p[2]*y[2]
    if t < t1:
        ydot[1] = 0.0
    else:
        ydot[1] = -p[0]*y[0]*y[1] + p[1]*y[2]
    ydot[2] = p[0]*y[0]*y[1] - p[1]*y[2] - p[2]*y[2]
    return ydot


ydot = np.zeros(3)
p = np.array([0.01, 0.25, 0.1])
y0 = [20.0, 100.0, 0.0]
t = np.linspace(0, 200, 2001)
t1 = 20.0

sol = odeint(ode_rhs, y0, t, args=(p, t1))


plt.figure(1)
plt.clf()

plt.subplot(3, 1, 1)
plt.plot(t, sol[:, 0])
plt.axvline(t1, color='r')
plt.grid(True)
plt.ylabel('y[0]')


plt.subplot(3, 1, 2)
plt.plot(t, sol[:, 1])
plt.axvline(t1, color='r')
plt.grid(True)
plt.ylabel('y[1]')
plt.ylim(0, 110)

plt.subplot(3, 1, 3)
plt.plot(t, sol[:, 2])
plt.axvline(t1, color='r')
plt.grid(True)
plt.ylabel('y[2]')
plt.xlabel('t')

plt.show()
```

A slight variation of the above method is to modify the system by adding a
parameter that is either 0 or 1.  When the parameter is 0, the equlibration system is solved, and when the parameter is 1, the full system is solved.  The code for `ydot[1]` (in my smaller example) is then

```
ydot[1] = full * (-p[0]*y[0]*y[1] + p[1]*y[2])
```

where `full` is the parameter.

To handle the equilibration phase, the system is solved once on 0 <= t < t1 with
`full=0`.  Then the final value of the equilibration solution is used as the
initial condition to the second solution, run with `full=1`.  The advantage of this method is that you are not forcing the solver to deal with the discontinuity.

Here's how it looks in code.

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.integrate import odeint
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


def ode_rhs(y, t, p, full):
    ydot[0] = -p[0]*y[0]*y[1] + p[1]*y[2] + p[2]*y[2]
    ydot[1] = full * (-p[0]*y[0]*y[1] + p[1]*y[2])
    ydot[2] = p[0]*y[0]*y[1] - p[1]*y[2] - p[2]*y[2]
    return ydot


ydot = np.zeros(3)
p = np.array([0.01, 0.25, 0.1])
y0 = [20.0, 100.0, 0.0]
t1 = 20.0  # Equilibration time
tf = 200.0  # Final time

# Solve the equilibration phase.
teq = np.linspace(0, t1, 100)
full = 0
soleq = odeint(ode_rhs, y0, teq, args=(p, full))

# Solve the full system, using the final point of the
# equilibration phase as the initial condition.
y0 = soleq[-1]
# Note: the system is autonomous, so we could just as well start
# at t0=0.  But starting at t1 makes the plots (below) align without
# any additional shifting of the time arrays.
t = np.linspace(t1, tf, 2000)
full = 1
sol = odeint(ode_rhs, y0, t, args=(p, full))

plt.figure(2)
plt.clf()
plt.subplot(3, 1, 1)
plt.plot(teq, soleq[:, 0], t, sol[:, 0])
plt.axvline(t1, color='r')
plt.grid(True)
plt.ylabel('y[0]')

plt.subplot(3, 1, 2)
plt.plot(teq, soleq[:, 1], t, sol[:, 1])
plt.axvline(t1, color='r')
plt.grid(True)
plt.ylabel('y[1]')
plt.ylim(0, 110)

plt.subplot(3, 1, 3)
plt.plot(teq, soleq[:, 2], t, sol[:, 2])
plt.axvline(t1, color='r')
plt.grid(True)
plt.ylabel('y[2]')
plt.xlabel('t')

plt.show()
```

And here's the plot that it generates (the plot from the first example is
almost exactly the same):
[image: plot of equilibration and full solutions]

Comment: Thank you very much - very eloquent and explained perfectly. Makes complete sense.

Answer (score 1):

This answer did not work me, as I needed to **alter my initial conditions periodically**. Therefore, I would like to propose alternative solution, which is to alternate conditions for differential equation inside the function itself:

We look at the value of t and adjust it:

```
if int(t) > 20:
    full = 1
else:
    full = 0
```

Here it is inside a function:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.integrate import odeint
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def ode_rhs(y, t, p, full):

    if int(t) > 20:
        full = 1
    else:
        full = 0

    ydot[0] = -p[0]*y[0]*y[1] + p[1]*y[2] + p[2]*y[2]
    ydot[1] = full * (-p[0]*y[0]*y[1] + p[1]*y[2])
    ydot[2] = p[0]*y[0]*y[1] - p[1]*y[2] - p[2]*y[2]
    return ydot

ydot = np.zeros(3)

# intial conditions
p = np.array([0.01, 0.25, 0.1])
y0 = [20.0, 100.0, 0.0]
t = np.linspace(0, 200, 100)
full = 0

# solve equation
solution = odeint(ode_rhs, y0, t, args=(p, full))

plt.figure()
plt.clf()
plt.subplot(3, 1, 1)
plt.plot(t, solution[:, 0])
plt.axvline(20, color='r')  # vertical line
plt.grid(True)
plt.ylabel('y[0]')

plt.subplot(3, 1, 2)
plt.plot(t, solution[:, 1])
plt.axvline(20, color='r')  # vertical line
plt.grid(True)
plt.ylabel('y[1]')
plt.ylim(0, 110)

plt.subplot(3, 1, 3)
plt.plot(t, solution[:, 2])
plt.axvline(20, color='r')  # x=20 vertical line
plt.grid(True)
plt.ylabel('y[2]')
plt.xlabel('t')

plt.show()
```

That allows to call the function to solve the equation exactly once.

- You don't have to mess with initial conditions from the previous step
- Easier to plot
- Code is more cleaner and easier to manage

And more importantly, you can now adjust parameters periodically inside the equation. For instance, say you have t = [0:200] and you want to change value of *full* every 20 steps, you can do so like this:

```
if int(t/20) % 2 == 0:
    full = 1
else:
    full = 0
```

[image: alternating value of the variable *full*]