# Control time step using odeint (Boost)

Tags: c++, boost, odeint

I am trying to learn solving ODE problem by using ODEINT library via the following example. However, when I output the result the time step is just jumping over 0; 1; 5.5; 25... Is there a way to control this time step to make it increment by "1". Thanks!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/array.hpp>

#include <boost/numeric/odeint.hpp>

using namespace std;
using namespace boost::numeric::odeint;

const double sigma = 0.0018;


typedef std::vector< double > state_type;

void my_ode( const state_type &x , state_type &dxdt , int t )
{
    dxdt[0] = sigma * x[0]*( 1 - x[0] );

}

void write_ode( const state_type &x , const double t )
{
    cout << t << '\t' << x[0] << endl;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    state_type x(1); // Initial condition, vector of 1 element (scalar problem)
     x[0] = 0.001;
    integrate( my_ode , x , 0.0 , 6000.0 , 1.0 , write_ode );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is a easy way to do this. The tutorial is full of examples.

You need to define a specific solver. A good choice might be a dense output solver, which has step size control and lets one compute the solution at arbitrary time steps. It might be used like

```
// not tested
state_type x(1);
x[0] = 0.001;
auto rkd = runge_kutta_dopri5<state_type>{};
auto stepper = make_dense_output(1.0e-6, 1.0e-6, rkd);
integrate_const(stepper, x, 0.0, 6000.0, 1.0, write_ode);
```

Comment: I tested your codes but did not work. However, this worked: state_type x = { 0.001 }; // initial conditions
    typedef dense_output_runge_kutta<controlled_runge_kutta<runge_kutta_dopri5<state_type> > > stepper_type;   integrate_const(stepper_type(), ode_system, x, 0.0, 500.0, 1.0);
One more question: How do we retrieve time "t" to be a global variable? I want to use that as condition for other functions (e.g. under my_ode())? Thanks

Comment: I don't understand your question about t to be a global variable. It is local and it will be passed around in ode by value, meaning that it might not be global. What do you want to do with it?

Comment: I want to use "t"to set up a condition under my_ode(): like: if (t<450) then dxdt[0]=0, and else dxdt[0] = sigma * x[0]*( 1 - x[0] );
This is very the same to this question of ODEINT but on python: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16520101/update-initial-condition-in-ode-solver-each-time-step/39029114#39029114

Comment: I think the question you asked needs a fixed stepsize integration. `integrate_const` is suitable.